# how to display featured image for single post for a specific category

Tags: functions, conditional-tags

I used this function to display featured images on top of single posts and it works great. But I need it to only apply to the category 'team' with an ID of 31.

I have tried every possible combination I can think of. When I use the conditional the featured image does not display no matter what.

Here is the code:

```
/* Code to Display Featured Image on top of the post */

add_action( 'genesis_before_entry', 'featured_post_image', 8 );
function featured_post_image() {
  if ( ! is_singular( 'post' ) )  return;
  if ( is_category( 31 ) ) {
    the_post_thumbnail( 'post-image' );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`is_category`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_category/) checks whether or not the current page is the Archive Page for the specified category, not if the current post is in the category. You want [`in_category`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/in_category/).

```
/* Code to Display Featured Image on top of the post */

add_action( 'genesis_before_entry', 'featured_post_image', 8 );
function featured_post_image() {
  if ( ! is_singular( 'post' ) )  return;
  if ( in_category( 31 ) ) {
    the_post_thumbnail( 'post-image' );
  }
}
```